# How to plot the prior, posterior and likelihood function from given data in python

Tags: bayesian, python, likelihood, prior, numpy

I wrote a simple bayesian program which calculates prior, posterior and likelihood in python.

```
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

cloudy = np.random.randint(2,size=(10,1))
rainy = np.random.randint(2,size=(10,1))

'''
Bayesian equation

p(rainy|cloudy) = (p(cloudy|rainy) * p(rainy))/p(cloudy)

'''

p_cloudy = cloudy.sum()/len(cloudy)
p_rainy = rainy.sum()/len(rainy)

p_cloudy_rainy = np.hstack((cloudy,rainy))
print("Cloudy, Rainy\n",p_cloudy_rainy)

p_cloudy_rainy = p_cloudy_rainy[p_cloudy_rainy[:,1]==1]
p_cloudy_rainy = p_cloudy_rainy[:,0].sum()/p_cloudy_rainy.shape[0]

p_rainy_cloudy = (p_cloudy_rainy*p_rainy)/p_cloudy


print("prior: {} posterior: {} likelihodd: {}".format(p_rainy,p_rainy_cloudy,p_cloudy_rainy))
```

After the calculation of prior, posterior and likelihood , How can I plot those values like this,
[image]

Comment: Looks like your events are discrete.  There are no parameters over which we can place priors. Though you could use Bayes rule to estimate these conditional probabilities, I think you're confusing Bayes' Rule with Bayesian modelling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example has discrete distribution. But you want to plot the PDF for Prior, Posterior and Likelihood. This is not correct.

You may want to plot [PMF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) for your rainy, cloudy example.